# All k-term sums of the first n natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

is there a formula that generates k-term sums of the first  $n$ natural numbers? The numbers are not allowed to repeat. For example, for $n=10$ and $k=4$, some possible sums would be $1+2+3+4, 2+6+7+8, 5+4+8+9$, etc. Some impossible sums would be $1+2+5+8+9, 4+6, 2+2+2+2, 6+2+3+2$, etc. Pardon the lack of formatting, I am writing from my phone in the car.

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are after.  Are you looking for the *number* of possible summations?  Do you treat $1+4$ differently than $2+3$ because the addends are different or do you treat them as the same since their total is the same?  Or... are you looking for a way to generate the *list* of possible summations (*or results of summations*)?

Comment: In general, the sum $\sum _{k=n+1}^{m}k$ equals $\frac{m(m+1)-n(n+1)}{2}$. You may write down each of your sum as combinations of sums of this type (that is, of sums of a certain number of consecutive integers).

Comment: One way to interpret your Question is whether there is an expression which yields all values (and only those values) that are sums of $k$ summands drawn (without replacement) from the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  However without seeing what use would be made, I'm doubtful that I've understood your request clearly enough to give a useful response.

Comment: Don't write from your phone in the car. That's dangerous to you and others.

Answer (score 5):

They are, in fact, all positive integers between the minimum possible sum

$$\frac{(k)(k+1)}{2}=1+2+3+...+k$$

and the maximum possible sum

$$kn-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}=(n-k+1)+(n-k+2)+...+n.$$

Can you show, by perturbing previous sums, why all of these sums can be reached?